# In C programming: Do I need to consider '\0' (null terminator) when mallocing space for a new string

Tags: c, malloc

For example, suppose I want to copy thing the string "str1" to a new string, "str2":

```
void function(const char* str1){
    char* str2;
    str2 = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(str1) + 1));
    strcpy(str2, str1);
    ...
}
```

Should the argument to malloc be:

```
sizeof(char) * (strlen(str1)+1)
```

or just:

```
sizeof(char) * strlen(str1)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you need to +1 — `strlen` returns the string length; to store a string you need storage for its length plus an extra spot for the `NULL` terminator.

That being said, in this specific example (which I'm sure is just that: an example to make the point), you can just use `strdup`.

Answer (score 1):

strcpy() functions copy the string including the terminating `\0' character, so you need +1.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course you have to account for the '\0'. So:

```
strlen(str1)+1U
```

Is what you want. Consider `strdup` in this case.

Comment: `strdup` is widely available, but is not defined by the C standard.

Comment: `strdup` is easy to write yourself though if you don't have it. If this is a common operation in your code, I'd write a function for it rather than repeating the same logic every time.

Comment: `1U` is to explicitly say that the constant `1` is `unsigned`, just like the return of C89 or later `strlen`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `malloc()` you could use `calloc()` which automatically null terminates for you.